# React- managing multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, progressive-web-apps

I am working on Progressive Web App which uses React. The problem I ecountred is that I am not sure how manage another page. There is one html file in the project called "index.html. Should I create more and somehow swich between them? I found library called [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/%20%22React%20Router) which seems to solve the problem in a diffrent way (because I need urls to change as well). I am not sure if I should develop that as a one dynamic page because I would have tens of diffrent pages. What is the best practise?

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of Reactjs, is to build your webapp as a single javascript web application.

React-router will manage the routing on your app via [the HTML5 history API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/History)

It can also manage the head of you HTML page with [React-Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) or other packages.
All you have to do is to include your app script into your single HTML page.

React-router v4 is, in my opinion, the best router as it is designed in a React-way, for this purpose.